# Unable to filter by date the array field of a Collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am struggling with MongoDb in order to achieve a desirable result.

My Collection looks like:

```
{
 _id: ...
 place: 1
 city: 6
 user: 306
 createDate: 2014-08-10 12:20:21,
 lastUpdate: 2014-08-14 10:11:01,
 data: [
   {
     customId4: 4,
     entryDate: 2014-07-12 12:01:11,
     exitDate: 2014-07-12 13:12:12
   },
   {
     customId4: 4,
     entryDate: 2014-07-14 00:00:01,
   },
   {
     customId4: 5,
     entryDate: 2014-07-15 11:01:11,
     exitDate: 2014-07-15 11:05:15
   },
   {
     customId4: 5,
     entryDate: 2014-07-22 21:01:11,
     exitDate: 2014-07-22 21:23:22
   },
   {
     customId4: 4,
     entryDate: 2014-07-23 14:00:11,
   },
   {
     customId4: 4,
     entryDate: 2014-07-29 22:00:11,
     exitDate: 2014-07-29 23:00:12
   },
   {
     customId4: 5,
     entryDate: 2014-08-12 12:01:11,
     exitDate: 2014-08-12 13:12:12
   },
 ]
}
```

So what I would like to achieve is the array data that meets the requirements of a certain interval and that has both, entryDate and exitDate values set.

For example, if I filter by the interval "2014-07-23 00:00:00 to 2014-08-31 00:00:00" I would like the result like:

```
{
  result: [
    {
       _id: {
           place: 1,
           user: 306
       },
       city: 6,
       place: 1,
       user: 306,
       data: [
          {
            customMap: 4,
            entryDate: 2014-07-22 21:01:11,
            exitDate: 2014-07-22 21:23:22
          },
          {
            customId4: ,
            entryDate: 2014-07-29 22:00:11,
            exitDate: 2014-07-29 23:00:12
          },
       ]
    }
  ],
  ok: 1
}
```

My custom mongodb query looks like (from, to and placeIds are variables properly configured)

```
db.myColl.aggregate(
    { $match: { 
        'user': 1, 
        'data.entryDate': { $gte: from, $lte: to },
        'place': { $in: placeIds },
    }},
    { $unwind : "$data" },
    { $project: {
        'city': 1, 
        'place': 1,
        'user': 1,
        'lastUpdate': 1,
        'data.entryDate': 1,
        'data.exitDate': 1,
        'data.custom': 1,
        fromValid: { $gte: ["$'data.entryDate'", from]},
        toValid: { $lte: ["$'data.entryDate'", to]}}
    },
        { $group: {
        '_id': {'place': '$place', 'user': '$user'},
        'city': {'$first': '$city'},
        'place': {'$first': '$place'},
        'user': {'$first': '$user'},
        'data': { '$push': '$data'}
}}
)
```

But this doesn't filter the way I want because it outputs every document that meets the $match operand conditions, inside the $project operand I am unable to define the condition (I don't know if this is how it has to be done in mongoDB)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track, but what you might be missing with the aggregation "pipeline" is that just like the "|" pipe operator in the unix shell you "chain" the pipeline stages together just as you would chain commands.

So in fact to can have a second [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage that does the filtering for you:

```js
db.myColl.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "user": 1, 
        "data.entryDate": { "$gte": from, "$lte": to },
        "place": { "$in": "placeIds" },
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$match": { 
        "data.entryDate": { "$gte": from, "$lte": to },
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "place": { "$first": "$place" },
        "city": { "$first": "$city" },
        "user": { "$first": "$user" },
        "data": { "$push": "$data" }
    }}
])
```

Using the actual `_id` of the document as a grouping key presuming that you want the document back but just with a filtered array.

From MongoDB 2.6, as long as your matching array elements are unique, you could just do the same thing within [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) using the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operators:

```js
db.myColl.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "user": 1, 
        "data.entryDate": { "$gte": from, "$lte": to },
        "place": { "$in": "placeIds" },
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "place": 1,
        "city": 1,
        "user": 1,
        "data": {
           "$setDifference": [
               { "$map": {
                   "input": "$data",
                   "as": "el",
                   "in": {"$cond": [
                       { "$and": [
                           { "$gte": [ "$$el.entryDate", from ] },
                           { "$lte": [ "$$el.entryDate", to ] }
                       ]},
                       "$$el",
                       false
                   ]}
               }},
               [false]
           ]
        }
    }}
 ])
```

That does the same logical thing by processing each array element and evaluating whether it meets the conditions. If so then the element content is returned, if not the `false` is returned. The `$setDifference` filters out all the `false` values so that only those that match remain.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is perfect. It's great!